# How can I write a file in Vim?

Tags: vim

I am following the vim tutorial on vimtutor and am trying to write a file.

When I type `:w` I get `E212: Can't open file for writing`.

When I type `:w !sudo tee %` I get

```
\Vim\vim81\tutor\tutor) was unexpected at this time.
shell returned 1
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can you press the `ESC` key and then type, `:echo(&readonly)`, followed by the `Enter` key? More than likely you are in a read only file (e.g. the tutorial is opened read only by default)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running `vimtutor`, it usually creates the working text file in `/tmp` directory.  My guess is that while working with vimtutor, you have accidentally set the file to an invalid path. Since it has somehow mangled the path, you should save it as a new file.

For example, you can do this by saving it as a new working text file in vimtutor:

```
:w /tmp/myvimtutor.txt
```

If you want to continue using the same text file in the future, you can then just run vim to its newly created file from the shell.

```
$ vim /tmp/myvimtutor.txt
```

Also, to verify your file path, you can type `:f` to show the current filename.  Perhaps it will reveal why you were having problem in the first place.